# Jquery addClass aplica mas não me da o resultado

Tags: jquery

Bom dia, estou com um problema, estou tentando fazer um efeito para o meu menu, quando o usúario passa do 200 no scroll o menu aumenta utilizando o `height: 85px;`, quando sobe o scroll ele remove a class que eu criei para `height: 85px;` deixando outra class entrar, mas não estou conseguindo aplicar no site, pois fiz o código, quando vou rolar o scroll ele adiciona a class **olhando no inspecte de element** mas não me trás o resultado que no caso seria aumentar o `heigth` do menu, eu estou utilizando o sass será que isso está me causando problema? segue o codigo abaixo:

movimenta.js:

```
$(function () {
    $('header').show();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            $('header').addClass('header-efeito');
        } else {
            $('header').removeClass('header-efeito');
        }
    });
});
```

_header.scss:

```
    .header-efeito {
        header {
            max-height: none;
            height: 130px;
        }
    }


/* voltar como estava */
.main {
    header{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
        max-height: 85px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: $white;
    }
}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar... Obrigado

Comment: As vezes o JQuery(mesmo sendo javascript) não está conseguindo interpretar o sass, faz um código css normal e tenta aplicar os efeitoss para ver!

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal do stack conseguir resolver o problema...

estava declarando a class e o header sendo que não precisava

codigo errado:

```
.header-efeito {
      header{
        height: 130px !important;
   }
}
```

codigo certo:

```
.header-efeito {

        height: 130px !important;
}
```